# Regular expression to match valid calls to Shadowbox.init()

Tags: php, regex

I want to know if a string is in another string at least once.

I want to check if `Shadowbox.init` then any (optionnal) combisaison of whitespace then `(` is inside $myString at least once.

- Shadowbox.init must be found (case sensitive)
- It can be followed by any number of white spaces (spaces, tabs, newlines...)
- The whitespaces or `init` is then followed by an opening parenthesis `(`

So far I have:

```
$matches = preg_match('/Shadowbox.init[\s]*(/', $myString);
```

Some examples:

```
/*
Shadowbox.init(); --> OK
Shadowbox.init ( ); --> OK
Shadowbox.init       (foo); --> OK
Shadowbox.init ); --> Bad missing (
Shadowbox.init --> Bad missing (
Shadowbox. init(); --> Bad space after dot
*/
```

Comment: Not sure what your question is here... what's not working with the regex you have?

Comment: It says "Compilation failed: missing )"

Comment: The '(' character in the regex needs to be escaped, as does the '.' in this case (since you want to match a literal period). An unescaped '(' creates a grouping in the regex.

Comment: Arent the brackets [] do a group too in regexps? Damn I hate the fact that multiple characters can do the same thing :)

Comment: They group things in different ways. Parens group things and capture them, so that you can reference them later. They also group for associativity. Brackets denote character classes, which is a way of defining a set of characters to match in the regex. For example, the character class `[abc]` would match one instance of either 1) the character 'a' 2) the character 'b' or 3) the character 'c'. On the other hand, `(abc)` would match the string 'abc' and capture it for referencing later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were nearly there:

```
$matches = preg_match('/Shadowbox\.init\s*\(/', $myString);
```

You need to escape the parenthesis and the dot. And you don't need to put brackets around `\s`.

Comment: Slowly learning... OK so 1) you escaped the dot with a backslash 2) escaped the ( with a backslash 3) removed [] between \s. Why 3 is needed? Can you explain?

Comment: The brackets are just not necessary - you need them only if you have more than one item inside the character class you're defining, like `[abc]`. Since `\s` is a single token, you can drop the brackets, but they don't hurt either.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: "Shadowbox.init" and "(" can be separated by ANY NUMBER/COMBINAISON of whitespaces.

Comment: There was a little more to the problem than that. :)